# Moving MovieClip to right with x and y coordinate [actionscript 3.0] automatically

Tags: actionscript-3

I try to make simple program in AS 3,
this is scenario :
I have a MovieClip in Linkage name is Hero,
and I want to move Hero to right with speed is 2, and if hero.x = 200 then Hero will stop at position x = 200, this is my simple code :

```
    var hero:Hero = new Hero();
        hero.x = 0;
        hero.y = 300;
        addChild(hero);

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateHero);
    function animateHero(event:Event) {

    if (hero.x <= 200){
        hero.play();
        } else { 
        hero.currentFrame(stop);
        }
        hero.x += 2;
    }
```

I try this code, it is running but show repeated error message in output panel:

```
    TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
        at SpriteMovement_fla::MainTimeline/animateHero()
```

my question :

Is my codes wrong?, if so, please tell me how the right codes.

Comment: I guess stop is your problem in currentFrame(stop) - did you defined stop enywhere?

Comment: no, i just want to stop hero when he was in hero.x = 200. please tell me what should I do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var hero:Hero = new Hero();
    hero.x = 0;
    hero.y = 300;
    addChild(hero);
    hero.play();
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateHero);
function animateHero(event:Event) {

    if (hero.x <= 200){
        hero.x += 2;
    } else { 
        hero.stop();
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateHero);
    }
}
```

I think this is what you wanted.

"currentFrame" is a value not a function. This is why that error showing.

Comment: Thanks dude..
your help is useful..
now hero can run and stop automatically

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken (it's a long time ago), you can just use `hero.stop()` instead of currentFrame(stop). I think the error is generated because AS3 doesn't know Hero is a movieclip, so casting it to a movieclip will cause flash to understand that the start and stop functions can be called on Hero.

Comment: previously I've tried using hero.stop ();
yes hero can stop moving but he still running and can't stop.